# Is there any React component that can show data like accordion

Tags: reactjs

I would like to create following React component that initially shown in collapsed mode (show less data) like below :

Component-Collapsed:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTv4R.png

Once the arrow clicked, the component expanded to the maximum size to show full data and the arrow direction is changed as per depicted below :

Component-Expanded:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSmkw.png

Appreciate any help.

Regards,

efends

Comment: Hi, StackOverflow is here to help you get over a problem you are encountering. This means that you should tell us what you tried, searched for and where you are blocked or where you failed. At this moment we will be able to help you resolve it. Here your post explain clearly what you want and thats great! But not what you did! So for us reading this. It's like you want us to dev for you. And thats not the purpose of this ! ;) 
For your next post try to be a little more precise about where you are in your dev and where you need our help (with some code samples maybe). Chears!

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to explore [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/), I'd recommend you to see the [Controlled Accordion](https://material-ui.com/components/expansion-panels/#controlled-accordion) component. You can simply do `npm install @material-ui/core` to get started.

If not that, you'd probably want to create it from scratch. See [this pen](https://codepen.io/manans77/pen/ZEYgxKP) I created (forked) for your convenience.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following logic:

```
// App.js

import React, {useState} from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className={`wrapp ${open ? 'open' : ''}`}>
        <h1>text one</h1>
        <h1>text one</h1>
        <h1>text one</h1>
        <h1>text one</h1>
        <h1>text one</h1>
        <button onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>open</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

style.css

```
// style.css

.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapp{
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.open{
  height: max-content;
}

button{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```